# Sharepoint 2010 foundation How to remove day view / week view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calendar

My concern is that when users click on the a specific day/week on the calendar, the calendar will change into day/week view, which I want to prevent from happening.

The goal is to fix the calendar scope to month view, so that clicking on the calendar will not bring up day/week view.

I have tried some searching on Google, I've seen people suggesting jQuery/JavaScript, however, because I'm new to SharePoint, I don't know where to put those code..

I've seen people suggesting this adding code:

```
`$dates = $('.ms-acal-summary-dayrow > td');
 $dates.each(function(){
     $(this).removeAttr("evtid");
     $(this).removeAttr("date");
 });`
```

or this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('td[evtid=day]').removeAttr('evtid');
     $('th[evtid=week]').removeAttr('evtid');
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure if they could work yet.. (because I don't know where to put them, I've tried masterpage and some CSS files under "_themes/28/" folder using sharepoint designer, but didn't work)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put jquery into content editor webpart which can be placed in a simple div tag.
Make sure that you place the jquery.js into your style library and make a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks, content editor webpart worked out! I didn't use div tag though. The jquery code seems only working with day view, any ideas about disabling week view?